# Adjusting arrows in a commutative diagram with tikzcd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to type the following diagram with `tikzcd`:

[image]

I end up with

[image]

by the following codes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathmorphing,arrows}
\tikzset{commutative diagrams/.cd,arrow style=tikz,diagrams={>=stealth'}}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
    M\times N \arrow{r}{\iota} \arrow[swap]{dr}{\varphi} & M\otimes_RN \arrow{d}{\Phi} \\
    & L
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

How can I adjust the position of the downright arrow? How can I change the arrow tip to be the one in the first picture?

Answer (score 4):

The `Computer Modern Rightarrow` arrow tip from the `arrows.meta` library looks a bit like the one in your image, if you modify its `width` and `length`, i.e.

```
>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[length=5pt,width=3pt]}
```

To move the arrow, you can for example make use the `start anchor` and `end anchor` keys, which are described in the manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % not arrows, but arrows.meta
\tikzset{
  commutative diagrams/.cd,
  arrow style=tikz,
  diagrams={>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[length=5pt,width=3pt]}},
}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
      M\times N \arrow{r}{\iota}
   \arrow[swap,
      start anchor={[shift={(-3pt,3pt)}]south east}, % fine tune start of arrow
      end anchor={[shift={(2pt,-4pt)}]north west} % fine tune end of arrow
      ]{dr}{\varphi}
    & M\otimes_RN \arrow{d}{\Phi} \\
    & L
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```